# How to include dynamic path in Quarkus Rest Client request?

Tags: java, quarkus, quarkus-rest-client

I'm working on a Quarkus application that uses a Rest Client to make HTTP requests to an external API. The endpoint is formed by a base url + a dynamic part (that comes from the UI) like *"/download/attachments/165667/test.txt?version=1&modificationDate=1684838964263&cacheVersion=1api=v2"*

How can I declare this dynamic part? I tried with @PathParam like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAbK3.png)
But it is not working, the special characters are escaped.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of problems here:

1.- REST Client is always encoding the PATH params. There is an open issue in GH to support the `@Encoded` annotation: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/23961

2.- But, the other problem is that if you use the `@Path` + `@PathParam` annotations, the query params you are using "version=1&modificationDate=1684838964263&cacheVersion=1api=v2" will not be ignored.

You can workaround the above problems by parsing the URI yourself and declaring your client like:

```java
@GET
@Path("/{part1}/{part2}")
String call(@PathParam("part1") String part1, @PathParam("part2") String part2, @RestQuery Map<String, String> queries);
```

However, I think the easiest solution for you is to create a ClientRequestFilter filter that populates the full dynamic URI from a string:

```java
@Provider
public class MyClientRequestFilter implements ClientRequestFilter {

    private static final String HEADER = "dynamic";

    @Override
    public void filter(ClientRequestContext requestContext) {
        String uri = requestContext.getHeaderString(HEADER);
        if (uri != null) {
            requestContext.setUri(URI.create(requestContext.getUri() + uri));
            requestContext.getHeaders().remove(HEADER);
        }
    }
}
```

Next, declare your client to populate the header that is being used in the filter:

```java
@GET
String call(@HeaderParam("dynamic") String dynamic);
```

Btw, you can have more information about the client request filters in https://quarkus.io/version/main/guides/rest-client-reactive#customizing-the-request.

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Did you know that you can use regex in your path ?
Check the [manual](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.0.0.GA/userguide/html/_PathParam.html)